# check if 0,1 and 1,0 patterns are present with 2 bitsets

Tags: bitwise-operators, bitset

Is it possible to check if `0 1` and `1 0` patterns appear within 2 bitsets with logical operators ?

For example, lets consider 1st bitset : `1 1 0 0`, and 2nd bitset `0 1 1 1`

In columns :

```
1  0
1  1
0  1
0  1
```

On the first line : we have `1 0` pattern and `0 1` on the third line, so these bitsets pass the test.

Bitsets `1 1 0 1` and `1 0 0 0` won't pass the test, because `0 1` pattern is not present.

I would like to use only logical operators (xor, and, or..) and not with a loop on every bits.

Comment: Are you using bit sets or integers? If you're using bit sets, what language and implementation are you using?

Comment: I am using bitset in c++

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check if there’s at least one bit set in both bitmaps that is unset in the other. That can be done with the following:

```
bool check_bitsets(uint64_t bitset1, uint64_t bitset2)
{
    uint64_t diff = bitset1 ^ bitset2;
    return (bitset1 & diff) && (bitset2 & diff);
}
```

or if we want to be generic and use `std::bitset`:

```
template<std::size_t N>
bool check_bitsets(std::bitset<N> bitset1, std::bitset<N> bitset2)
{   
    auto diff = bitset1 ^ bitset2;
    return (bitset1 & diff).any() && (bitset2 & diff).any();
}
```

First we use [XOR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR) to find the bits that are only set in one or the other but not both. Then, we need to check that both bitmaps have at least one of the bits in `diff` set.